# What does "main" when I use currentThread() mean? Am I using multithreading properly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently getting familiar with threads and multithreading in Java. I'm doing a simple exercise where I have to split the array into equal partitions based on N number of threads that I pass to my function at run time.

However, I'm curious to know if I'm actually executing mergeSort() in each thread, or is it just running as a single thread. I did a for loop, and it was something like Thread.start() followed by a try-catch block, where Thread.join() would be called and then I would print the name using Thread.currentThread(). However, I get the word "main" throughout the entire execution.

Does this mean I'm not really multithreading? My thinking would be that I'd get something like Thread-0..., but I only get that if I do Thread.getName();

Please advise.

```
for (MedianMultiThread mmt : threadList) {
    mmt.start();
    try {
        mmt.join();
        sortedSubArrays.add(mmt.getInternal());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Realized that I was running currentThread() in the thread, but when I ran it in the run() method, then I got different results. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Most likely your code isn't as multithreaded as you think, but there is no way to know unless you include the code you are running.

Comment: This is because your `currentThread()` call is made from the main thread...

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You may want to consider writing your class by implementing a Runnable and using an Executor to run it in N threads instead of creating and managing threads yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, above is the fragment of my code. I've only included the main thread block. The rest are not related. If you're curiuos what's running in the Thread.run() function, it's mergeSort.

Comment: @bryancresswell So where do you output `thread.currentThread()`?

Comment: Just a note however, if you join the thread immediately after starting it, there is little point in using multiple threads in the first place, since they will all execute sequentially, one after the other.

Comment: @TobiasG I output `Thread.currentThread()` after `sortedSubArrays.add(mmt.getInternal())`

Comment: @JBNizet how then would I be able to make something truly multithreaded?

Comment: By starting all the threads, then joining them all, then accumulating all the results

Comment: @JBNizet So you're saying something like a for loop to start all the threads, and then a separate for loop to join all the threads?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `thread.currentThread()` method confuses a lot of people.  `thread.currentThread()` does *not* return the "current thread" unless you happen to think that "current thread" means, the thread that calls the function.

That's what `thread.currentThread()` actually does:  It returns a reference to the thread that called it.  If it's always returning "main" in your program, then that means that your program only ever calls it from the main() thread.

---

The name comes from a long time ago when most computers had only one CPU, and it was supposed to mean something to the guy who was writing the thread scheduling code.  If you're writing the scheduler for a single CPU machine, then there can never be more than one thread running at any given time.  It's natural to call it "the current thread."

The system call that returns the identity of the current thread in an old-school-Unix-style operating system running on a single CPU system could only ever return the identity of the thread that called it.

That turned out to be very useful in user-space programs.

The idea of a "current thread" doesn't mean much on modern multi-processor systems, but a system call that returns the identity of the calling thread still is every bit as useful as ever.

Unfortunately, we're stuck with the old name for it.

---

P.S.,  This never makes any sense:

```
mmt.start();
try {
    mmt.join();
    ...
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

There's never any reason to have two (or more) threads unless they can both do something useful at the same time.  In your code example, one thread starts a second thread, and then the first thread does *nothing* except wait for the second thread to finish.

You might just as well have done all the work in the first thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check in your code, whether function `Thread.currentThread()`  is called from the actual executing worker threads (and not from the main thread). This means, you need to put your `Thread.currentThread()` output inside the `run()` methods of the sort-worker threads.

Second advice is that threads are running randomly. I don't think that's the issue, but you need to keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Yes I am aware that threads run randomly. In the above code fragment, `Thread.currentThread()` is called after the join method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You need to actually start **all** threads, then join them **all** back together,

```
// start all of them
for (MedianMultiThread mmt : threadList) {
    mmt.start();
}

// join all back to main thread
try {
    mmt.join();
    sortedSubArrays.add(mmt.getInternal());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

// ... inside your worker thread's run() method

public void run(){
    System.out.println("Thread: "+Thread.currentThread());
    // do actual work...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It it is always printing "main", this means that the piece of code which is printing the name of the thread is executed by main thread always, and so that piece is not multithreaded. It would have been better if you had shown the exact code.